# Ionic 3 Firebase Google Auth stoped working in Android device

Tags: android, firebase, ionic3, angularfire2, ionic-native

My app worked perfectly until i tried to implement notifications, got firebase refused to connect and 404 errors when running on android device but everything worked perfectly on browser. Then reinstalled every plugin and modules, problem with firebase connection solved but the Google native login method not working at all, not even throwing any error

```
signInWithGoogle() { 
    if (this.platform.is('cordova')) {
        this.nativeGoogleLogin();
    }else{
        this.webGoogleLogin().then(()=>{});
    }
}
async nativeGoogleLogin(): Promise<void>{
    try {
        this.loading.present();
        const gplusUser = await this.gplus.login({
            'webClientId':'******',
            'offline':true,
            'scopes':'profile email'
        }) 
        console.log('NativeLogin');
        return await this.afAuth.auth.signInWithCredential(
            firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider.credential(gplusUser.idToken))

        // return await this.afAuth.auth.signInAndRetrieveDataWithCredential(
        //     firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider.credential(gplusUser.idToken))
        .then(data =>{
            this.loading.dismiss();
            console.log(data);
            this.updateUserData(data.user);
        }).catch(err =>{
            this.loading.dismiss();
            console.log('NativeLoginError',err);
        })
    } catch (error) {
        this.loading.dismiss();
        console.error('NativeLoginError',error); 
    }
}
```

the async methon is not even console loging the text.

> console.log('NativeLogin');

I double checked the webClientId. Am struggling to solve this problem

Comment: whats your cordova android version?

Comment: @fahadsk Cordova android 7.1.0 was giving androidManifist.xml error, So downgraded to cordova-android: 6.4.0

Comment: hav u checked downgrading to 6.3.0?

Comment: Yeah, Just now checked, It did not work right away after downgrading to 6.3.0, It worked after i remove the native-firebase Plugin. I wonder if the problem is because of native-firebase plugin itself. Thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

So you started seeing an error when you installed Firebase Notifications? FCM? I would start by uninstalling that, and seeing if the issue persists. Sometimes plugins have conflicting dependencies, and it messes with one another.

Did you install FCM while you had the application running? In my experience, it will mess up the hot-reload, and it will no longer know where things are supposed to be properly located, so a simple stop and start should fix that if that was the case.

Try running `ionic doctor check` this will fix any issues that the ionic project has run into on the CLI side of things.

Also, a little bit of cleaning up your code, to make it easier to follow.

```
signInWithGoogle() { 
    if (this.platform.is('cordova')) {
        this.nativeGoogleLogin().then(data => {
    this.loading.dismiss();
    this.updateUserData(data.user);
}).catch(err => { console.log('Native login error: ', JSON.stringify(err); });
    } else {
        this.webGoogleLogin();
    }
}

nativeGoogleLogin(): Promise<void> { // Personally I would take this out of the try catch because you already are catching the error with the .catch of your promise.

this.loading.present();
const gplusUser = await this.gplus.login({
            'webClientId':'******',
            'offline':true,
            'scopes':'profile email'
        });
return await this.afAuth.auth.signInWithCredential(
            firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider.credential(gplusUser.idToken));
}
```

Another thing to check is to see if you are actually calling the signInWithGoogle() method, because that's a mistake I used to make a lot when I was first starting out.

Also try inputting console.log messages everywhere, my personal favorite thing to do is the following, especially while developing.

```
console.log('File-name.ts: What-Im-Attempting-to-do: status(error, success or JSON.stringify(data);');
```

That way it makes it easier to track down your errors, instead of having to memorize what each error is supposed to be apart of.

If all of that doesn't work, try removing your platform completely, and re-adding it.

```
ionic cordova platform rm ios/android 
ionic cordova platform add ios/android
```

Hope this helps somewhat!

Comment: 1) I have reverted back, uninstalled all the plugins I have installed for notifications, 2) I did doctor check and i fixed 1 issue with some plugin update and it did not fix the issue. 3) checked signInWithGoogle() method is running and inside nativeGoogleLogin() I kept TryCatch, outside tryCatch running but the inside isn't. 4) I removed platform and plugins and reinstalled multiple times and it didnot work. I even created a entirely new project copied src and package.json into the new project and ran it and even the new app is also not working. :( :(

Comment: Thank you for the help, it seems the problem with the cordova-android version, downgraded to 6.3.0, and also problem with native-firebase plugin.